# perl fomatting array print out

Tags: perl, formatting

this is the data It is a list of ticket assignments in and IRC channel.

```
07:28:16 AM WJ INC1013210983
07:47.34 AM PP INC1013234284
08:48:54 AM AP INC1013212834
08:57:24 AM II INC1013212245
09:58:12 AM EB INC1013210008
10:28:22 AM JK INC1013210008
11:28:35 AM WJ INC1013212345
12:28:23 AM LC INC1013212290
01:19:15 AM WJ INC1013219946
02:03:16 AM JK INC1013213945
02:13:47 AM LC INC1013216958
03:32:52 AM WJ INC1013212290
03:52:01 AM BJ INC1013212280
```

This script takes the assignments and strips out the Europeans, and then sets the order for the American crew.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
my @team = ("AP","II","DS","WJ", "JK","LC","BJ") ;
my ( $team_regex ) = map {qr /$_/} join "|", map {quotemeta} @team;
my @orderdTeam ;
my @uni_orderdTeam ;
my @rev_orderdTeam ;

my $filename = shift @ARGV ;
open(my $fh, '<', $filename) or die "Could not open file $filename $!";
while (my $line = <$fh> ) {
    if ( $line =~ /^($team_regex)/ ) {
        push @orderdTeam, $1;
    }
}
close $fh;

print "AMER team members : @team\n";
print "Ordered: @orderdTeam\n";
@rev_orderdTeam = reverse @orderdTeam ;
print "Reverse: @rev_orderdTeam\n" ;

for my $uni (@rev_orderdTeam) {
    if ( ! grep( /$uni/, @uni_orderdTeam)) {
    push ( @uni_orderdTeam, $uni) ;
    }
}
print "Unique reversed : @uni_orderdTeam";
```

results

```
$ ./spliton_colon_duplicate.pl delegate20190628
AMER team members : AP II DS WJ JK LC BJ
Ordered: WJ AP II JK WJ LC WJ JK LC WJ BJ
Reverse: BJ WJ LC JK WJ LC WJ JK II AP WJ
Unique reversed : BJ WJ LC JK II AP
```

I would like to get results more like this :

```
Formatting          Team members
------------------|---------------------------------
AMER team members : AP II DS WJ JK LC BJ
Ordered           : WJ AP II JK WJ LC WJ JK LC WJ BJ
Reverse           : BJ WJ LC JK WJ LC WJ JK II AP WJ
Unique reversed   : BJ WJ LC JK II AP
```

Comment: Either do some trivial math or use a table module.

Comment: See also [Perl6::Form](https://metacpan.org/pod/Perl6::Form)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example using [Perl6::Form](https://metacpan.org/pod/Perl6::Form):

```
use Perl6::Form;
# [...]
my @labels = ('AMER team members', 'Ordered', 'Reverse', 'Unique reversed');
print form
  ' Formatting         Team members         ',
  '------------------|----------------------',
  '{[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[} : {[[[[[[{*}[[[[[[[[[[[}', 
  \@labels, ["@team", "@orderdTeam", "@rev_orderdTeam", "@uni_orderdTeam"];
```

**Output**:

```
 Formatting         Team members
------------------|----------------------
AMER team members : AP II DS WJ JK LC BJ
Ordered           : WJ AP II JK WJ LC WJ JK LC WJ BJ
Reverse           : BJ WJ LC JK WJ LC WJ JK II AP WJ
Unique reversed   : BJ WJ LC JK II AP
```